# Oracle / PLSQL - Using column results in a where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've been trying to do something very simple but still can't.
I am trying to interate over a table and use each row of a column in a where clause to display a query.

For example:

I want to retrieve all users from dba_users pass it to a where clause in a query to show for example account_status and profile for every user. But I want to do it in a way so I can turn the result into many html tables.

I've tried too many things really, so I will post something that doesn't work but which I think will show the problem I am having,

```
BEGIN
 FOR i IN (SELECT username from dba_users order by 1)
 LOOP
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select account_status from dba_users where username like ''||i.username||''';
 END LOOP;
 END;
 /
```

EDIT: Here's is another example of what I want to achieve:

1. Read 2 SQL_IDs from V$SQL

   SQL> select sql_id from v$sql where rownum < 3;

   ### SQL_ID

   9avfy3fv2wq2x
   0ywp98ffdz77f
2. Use those returned IDs to gather some performance info and get the results in two result sets

-- HTML Markup

```
set markup HTML ON HEAD " -  
" -  
BODY "" -  
TABLE "border='1' align='center' summary='Script output'" -  
SPOOL ON ENTMAP ON PREFORMAT OFF  

select sql_id, loads_total from dba_hist_sqlstat where sql_id like '9avfy3fv2wq2x';  
select sql_id, loads_total from dba_hist_sqlstat where sql_id like '0ywp98ffdz77f';
```

And I get the following results

```
SQL_ID        LOADS_TOTAL  
------------- -----------  
9avfy3fv2wq2x          21  

SQL_ID        LOADS_TOTAL  
------------- -----------  
0ywp98ffdz77f          12
```

Using the markup tag, this translates into:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNmjZ.png)

Thanks in advance for your time,

od

Comment: You have to select into something - use a cursor.

Comment: Run a simple query that gets the necessary data.  Use application code to display it.

Comment: I can't, because what I want is separate results and if I do a select into, it tells me that ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using a cursor:

```
 DECLARE
    CURSOR USERS IS
      SELECT username FROM dba_users ;

 BEGIN

    FOR user in USER
    LOOP
       SELECT account_status FROM dba_users WHERE username = user;
    END LOOP;

 END;
```

Comment: It gives me an error: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 9, column 8:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use some temporary table to store your data from each select and then you can process it further.

The other option is using `TABLE TYPE OF xxx` that you populate in your loop. 
You can see how to use it later by the second part that displays results.

```
 DECLARE
    CURSOR USERS IS
      SELECT username FROM dba_users ;

    TYPE resultType IS TABLE OF NVARCHAR2(80) ;
    result resulttype := resulttype();

    indx NUMBER(10) :=0;
 BEGIN

  -- we insert data from some selects
  FOR user in USERs
    LOOP
        result.extend();
        indx := indx + 1 ;
       SELECT account_status into result(indx) FROM dba_users WHERE username = user.username;

    END LOOP;


  -- and now we will display content 
    FOR i IN result.FIRST .. result.LAST
   LOOP
       dbms_output.put_line(result(i));
  END LOOP;

 END;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your effort. I edited my original post to clarify what the end result should look like. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You are not far away with your code.

```
declare
    v_account_status dba_users.account_status%type;
BEGIN
 FOR cur_users IN (SELECT username from dba_users order by 1)
 LOOP
   SELECT account_status INTO v_account_status -- you need to save somewhere 
                                               -- your value of account_status
          FROM dba_users 
          WHERE username LIKE cur_users.username; -- cur_users is the 
                                                  -- current row of dba_users
    -- do something with v_account_status, like
    -- htp.prn(cur_users.username || ' has account status ' || v_account_status);
 END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you trying to acheive this kind of result. However this will work only when dynamic query that you are executing is fetching a single result. If your dynamic query is fetching multiple result you can use variable of collection type to store the result using a bulk collect and then loop through the list to display the output.

```
    DECLARE
       v_sql         VARCHAR2 (4000);
       v_user_name   VARCHAR2 (400);
    BEGIN
       FOR i IN (SELECT   username
             FROM     dba_users
             WHERE    ROWNUM < 5
             ORDER BY 1) LOOP
          v_sql :=
            'select account_status from dba_users where username= '''
         || i.username
         || '''';

          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql
          INTO              v_user_name;

          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('v_Sql:' || v_sql || ' v_user: ' || v_user_name);
       END LOOP;
    END;
    /
```

Comment: sadly in some cases it does return more than one row, thanks anyway!